# Is there a way to make a custom animation for recyclerview layout manager change? (animate all items)

Tags: android, android-animation

SO Basically I want this

[image]

The only idea I have so far is to programatically generate the view items (without any listview/recyclerview) and aniamate them based on the clicked position. But I was wondering if there was some way to make a custom layout manager change animation (that wont make the phone blow up preferably). Any help would be appreciated :)